# Converting a dataframe which contains list into a csv with r

Tags: r, text-mining

I am new to R and I am facing difficulties to convert my dataframe (named dffinal) which contains list into a csv.

I tried the following code which gave a csv that is not usable:

```
dput(dffinal, file="out.txt")
new <- source("out.txt")
write.csv2(dffinal,"C:/Users\\final.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I tried all the option but I found nothing! Here is a sample of my dataframe:

```
dput(head(dffinal[1:2]))

structure(list(V1 = list("I heard about your products and I would like to give it a try but I'm not sure which product is better for my dry skin, Almond products or Shea Butter products? Thank you", 
    "Hi,\n\nCan you please tell me the difference between the shea shower oil limited edition and the other shower gels?  I got a sample of one in a kit that had a purple label on it.  (Please see attached photo.)  I love it!\nBut, what makes it limited edition, the smell or what?   It is out of stock and I was wondering if it is going to be restocked or not?\n\nAlso, what makes it different from the almond one?\n\nThank you for your help.", 
    "Hello, Have you discontinued  Eau de toilette", "I both an eGift card for my sister and she hasn't received anything via her email\n\nPlease advise \n\nThank you \n\n cann", 
    "I do not get Coco Pillow Mist. yet. When are you going to deliver it? I need it before January 3rd.", 
    "Hello,\nI wish to follow up on an email I just received from Lol, notifying\nme that I've \"successfully canceled my subscription of bun Complete.\"\nHowever, I didn't request a cancelation and was expecting my next scheduled\nfulfillment later this month. Could you please advise and help? I'd\nappreciate it if you could reinstate my subscription.\n"), 
    V2 = list("How long can I keep a product before opening it? shea butter original hand cream large size 5oz, i like to buy a lot during sales promotions, is this alright or should i only buy what i'll use immediately, are these natural organic products that will still have a long stable shelf life? thank you", 
        "Hi,\nI recently checked to see if my order had been delivered, and I only received my gift box and free sample. Can you please send the advent calendar? Does not seem to have been included in the shipping. Thank you", 
        "Is the gade fragrance still available?", "I previously contacted you because I purchased your raspberry lip scrub.  When I opened the scrub, 25% of the product was missing.  Your customer service department agreed to send me a replacement, but I never received the replacement rasberry lip scrub.  Could you please tell me when I will receive the replacement product?  Thanks, me", 
        "To whom it may concern:\n\nI have 3 items in my order:  1 Shea Butter Intensive Hand Balm and 2 S‚r‚nit‚ Relaxing Pillow Mist.  I have just received the hand balm this morning.  I was wondering when I would receive the two bottles of pillow mist.\n\nThanks and regards,\n\nMe", 
        "I have not received 2X Body Scalp Essence or any shipment information regarding these items.  Please let me know if and when you will be shipping these items, otherwise please credit my card.  Thanks")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
dffinal %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), unlist)) %>%
    write_csv('result.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have list of only length 1 for all the rows as shared in the example using `unlist` will work -

```
dffinal[] <- lapply(dffinal, unlist)
```

If the length of list is greater than 1 use -

```
dffinal[] <- lapply(dffinal, sapply, toString)
```

Write the data with `write.csv` -

```
write.csv(dffinal, 'result.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that worked very well! In my case I used write.csv2 instead which worked better.